# How can I add more than one logo to my beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, graphics

My institute requires to put three logos to all presentations. How can I add more than one logo to my beamer presentation?

Comment: On the title page only or on every slide?

Comment: On all slides optimal, but all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Beamer provides `\logo{<logo code>}` to set the logo(s). You could just add all three logos in there using three `\includegraphics` command (or PGF image commands). Where they are placed depends on your chosen scheme. If you want them a little larger on the title page you can insert the defined logo(s) manually `\insertlogo` e.g. inside a `\scalebox`.

The following code adds three scaled logos with one space as a separator into the right border. The default (blank) scheme puts them into the lower right corner.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Me}
\title{Presentation}
\logo{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logo1}~%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logo2}~%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logo3}%
}
\institute{Three Kings\\\scalebox{2}{\insertlogo}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle}
\frame{text}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Tyger! Tyger! Burning bright!

Comment: ¡Only @Martin Scharrer's hand dare frame that fearful symmetry!

Answer (score 7):

you can have several logos on the page. The question is only where they should appear. Here an example for the second one in the sidebar.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=2.25ex,width=2.5\baselineskip]{institut-logo}{zedat}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.3cm]{uni}{fu-berlin}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{uni}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\raisebox{-2ex}{\pgfuseimage{institut-logo}}
  \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hfill
  \usebeamertemplate{navigation symbols}\hfill
  \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Das Logo}
\begin{block}{Ein Beispiel mit der Umgebung \texttt{block}}
Es ist offensichtlich, dass wir hier zwei Logos auf der Folie haben.
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I needed to put three logos on the title page too.

I solved the problem in a very dummy way, but it worked!
I created a .jpg with the three logos on it, so I just need to insert one picture, but that picture has three logos in it. Remember to set a proper dimension now that your picture is a rectangle and not a square anymore